# state type change after update in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is what I want to do:

I wrote a function that gets the value of an input as a parameter.

`<input onChange={this.toggleReason} className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value={rfl} />`

Then it triggers the following function that does this: it checks for the presence of the input value in the state (that is initially an Array). If value is already in the array ==> remove the value, else if the value isn't already in the array ==> add the value to the array.

```
this.state = {
  selectedReasonsForLeaving: [] // initial state
}
```

---

```
  toggleReason = e => {
    console.log(typeof this.state.selectedReasonsForLeaving);
    const toggler = this.state.selectedReasonsForLeaving.find(elem => {
      return elem === e.target.value}
    );
    if (toggler !== e.target.value) {
      this.setState({selectedReasonsForLeaving: this.state.selectedReasonsForLeaving.push(e.target.value)}
    );
    } else {
      this.setState({selectedReasonsForLeaving: this.state.selectedReasonsForLeaving.filter(elem => elem !== toggler)}
    );
    }
    console.log(this.state.selectedReasonsForLeaving);
  }
```

It works well when the function is triggered for the very first time, but the second time it is triggered, I get the following error:

`TypeError: _this.state.selectedReasonsForLeaving.find is not a function`

for this line: `const toggler = this.state.selectedReasonsForLeaving.find({ ... })`

notice that `console.log(typeof this.state.selectedReasonsForLeaving);` outputs `object` the first time, but `number` the second time.

How can I change my function so that it works well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push` returns the number of elements pushed into the array. You could do something like this:

#### Code

```
if (toggler !== e.target.value) {
    this.state.selectedReasonsForLeaving.push(e.target.value)
    this.setState({
        selectedReasonsForLeaving: this.state.selectedReasonsForLeaving
    });
}
```

But modifying the state directly is not recommended. So, just use `concat`, which returns a new array:

#### Code

```
if (toggler !== e.target.value) {
    this.setState({
        selectedReasonsForLeaving: this.state.selectedReasonsForLeaving.concat(e.target.value)
    });
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is the official reference of `concat`.

Let me know if this worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

`push` method on array returns the length of the array after appending the value to array and hence you get this error. Make use of `concat` instead

```
this.setState({
    selectedReasonsForLeaving: this.state.selectedReasonsForLeaving.concat([e.target.value])
})
```